# Error 404 Not Found when making a POST request to localhost API endpoint

Tags: javascript, express

I'm encountering a 404 Not Found error when attempting to make a POST request to `"/api/auth/signup"` in my JavaScript application. I am trying to build a MERN application for a Modern Real Estate Marketplace.

Here is my code:

The sign up file

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import loginImg from "../assets/login.png";

export default function SignUp() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({})

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await fetch("/api/auth/signup",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      }
    );
    console.log('Response:', res);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
  }

  console.log(formData);

  return (
    <div>
      <div><img><img</img>`</div>`
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
          <div>
            <input type='text' placeholder='username' id="username" onChange={handleChange}></input>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type='email' placeholder='email' id="email" onChange={handleChange} ></input>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type='password' placeholder='password' id="password" onChange={handleChange} ></input>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p><input type='checkbox'></input>Remember me</p>
          </div>
          <button>Sign Up</button>
          <p>Already have an account?</p>
          <button><Link to={"/sign-in"}>Sign In</Link></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

vite.config

```js
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:3000",
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: \[react()\],
});
```

index.js

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import authRouter from "./routes/auth.route.js";
import userRouter from "./routes/user.route.js";
dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO)
  .then( () => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB!");
  })
  .catch((err) =\> {
    console.log(err);
  });

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});

app.use("/api/user", userRouter);
app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  const message = err.message || "Internal Server Error";
  return res.status(statusCode).json({
    success: false,
    statusCode,
    message,
  });
});
```

Auth controller

```js
import bcryptjs from "bcryptjs";
import User from "../models/user.model.js";

export const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  const hashedPassword = bcryptjs.hashSync(password, 10);
  const newUser = new User({ username, email, password: hashedPassword });
  try {
    await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json("User created successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

User model

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
}, { timestamps: true });

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

What I've Tried:

I've double-checked the URL to ensure it's correct.
I've inspected the network request in the browser's developer tools, and the request is being made as expected.
I manually added the "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup" instead of the /api/auth/signup"
and I still get the error. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The error message in the console: POST http://localhost:5173/api/auth/signup 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perform these 2 checks

1. run only backed server, forget about frontend,just test your backend API with POSTMAN / CURL.
2. Check your method type "GET/POST", in the Backend server.

Comment: the backend works, i can upload an user, but when i now try from the front end i get:
POST http://localhost:5173/api/auth/sign-up 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: it works fine now, i fixed it :) But thanks, your answer gave me some hope, that the mistake was only in the frontend part :)

Comment: great!!. 500 error mean, at least hitting api.
its good error, 404 means, even its not reaching api.
great man

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've never worked with vite, but what you can try is:

- try to remove 'proxy' object from vite config and use this url in fetch 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup' directly (instead of /api/auth/signup)

If it will work after this change, then it means that the problem was in URL in fetch and vite proxy. We should check how it works exactly.

Comment: I had tried that already, the mistake was a single - in the frontend part. But thanks :)

Comment: Did you try to remove 'proxy' from vite? it matters

Comment: As I see, if you remove 'proxy' from vite config and replace url in fetch, it should work. But it's better to check. If you have time it will be nice to know that it works 

Comment: yes, i did, i hid it in a comment section, and then added the localhost:3000/api/auth.... it was the same

Comment: and thank you very much, it was also helpful :) i will have that in mind when working on future projects